# On the life of a temporary object during expression templates

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, expression-templates

I am trying to understand an aspect of [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

Let's say we are applying the technique to matrices.

Suppose we have three concrete matrices `a,b,c` of type `Matrix<double, ConcreteMatrix<double>>`. Here the class `Matrix<double, T>` is just a shell that contains a member of type `T`. The `ConcreteMatrix<double>` is the actual matrix class.

In expression templates `operator+()` applied to two objects `a + b`, returns an object of type `Matrix<double, Sum<type(a),type(b)>>`, where I wrote `type(a)` and `type(b)` to not make the code shorter and easier to read.

Inside, the class `Sum<T,S>` stores two ** constant references** to the objects `a` and `b`.

My question arises when computing `(a + b) + c`. Well, to be more precise computing `Matrix<double, ConcreteMatrix<double>> d = (a + b) + c`. Let me recall here that it is `operator=` the one that takes care of actually doing the computation and filling up `d` with the results.

We have that `operator+(a, b)` returned that `Matrix` which is really a `Sum` inside. This object is temporary, if I understand it correctly. Let's call it `pab`. Now it is the time to execute `operator+(pad, c)` This one returns an object of type `Matrix<double,Sum<type(pad),type(c)>>`, which contains **constant references** to `pab` and to `c`. Let's call this object `ppabc`.

I understand how pab was 'alive' in the scope of the body of `operator+(pad,c)`. So, it is okay to create `ppabc` containing a reference to `pab`.

**Question:** But what happens when we go outside `operator+(pad, c)`? Isn't `pab` supposed to 'die' when we go outside `operator+(pad, c)`? This doesn't seem to be the case. Why? (I have a executed the implementation as written in Todd Veldhuizen and David Vandevoorde's book and it works fine.) That means that somehow the temporary `pab` still lives outside the body of `operator+(pad, c)` and the object that this operator returns can still access its reference to `pab` and ask for the values it contains.

I want to understand exactly what is the underlying reason why this temporary lives beyond the scope I would have imagined because I want to apply the technique of expression templates to get lazy evaluation for other functions, say `exp()`. I ran into troubles (execution errors due to a temporary getting destroyed). The errors disappeared when instead of a reference I stored a concrete object inside `Matrix<double, Exponential<type(a)>>`. So understanding the questions above would help.